# I am using Boolean variables to print the number of days in a calendar days. The outputs aren't what I am expecting

Tags: java

**I am trying to write a program which shows the number of days in a given month of a year. The outputs for the month of February, non leap years (no output) and the months having 30 days in leap years is incorrect (output is 29). How could I resolve this?**

```java
public class Q11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner number1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner number2 = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter the month (1-12)");
        int month = number1.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the year");
        int year = number2.nextInt();

        int number_of_days = 0;


        boolean N1 = (month == 1) ||
                (month == 3) ||
                (month == 5) ||
                (month == 7) ||
                (month == 8) ||
                (month == 10) ||
                (month == 12);
        boolean N2 = (month == 2) && (year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);
        boolean N3 = (month == 2) && (year % 400 <= 1) || (year % 4 <= 1) && (year % 100 == 0);
        boolean N4 = (month == 4) ||
                (month == 6) ||
                (month == 9) ||
                (month == 11);

        if (N1)
            System.out.println(". This month has 31 days");
        else if (N2)
            System.out.println(". This month has 29 days");
        else if (N3)
            System.out.println(". This month has 28 days");
        else if (N4)
            System.out.println(". This month has 30 days");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

You run into a problem due to the fact how the program evaluates your boolean expressions. Remember the rules for boolean precedence. `&&` is evaluated first and takes precedence. Also, the formula is evaluated from left to right. Operator precedence can be overruled with the correct setting of parentheses.

E.g. if you have `a && b || c`, `a && b` is evaluated first, after which we evaluate its result against `|| c`. But: `a && (b || c)` is evaluated by first evaluating `b || c` and then evaluating this result against `&& a`.

In your case, when you enter e.g. `month = 4` and `year = 2020` the following happens:

- The rule `n1` is skipped - `month` is not listed.
- The rule `n2` is evaluated - `month` is not equals to two and the year is not divisible by `400`; so far everything goes to plan. But now - the next `||` comes around to bite you. The `year` is divisible by 4 AND it is not divisible by 100. The program now incorrectly prints `29`.
- The rules `n3` and `n4` are solved like `n2` and are left as an exercise for the reader :)

## Solution

Easiest way is to understand why `n2` is failing and optimize the formula. Since this is a homework task I don't want to solve it for you.

## General

- One scanner instance on `System.in` is enough.
- Your variable names should follow the [Java naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), `lowerCaseCamelCase` instead of `snake_case` and `N1`.

### Parting thought

Try using a `switch` statement on `month` - it will make your code a bit easier to understand. Finally: Good luck in your studies.

Comment: It did not come across to me that when N2 is evaluated, the logic resets after | |. The optimisation did help and I will be renaming the variables as per feedback. Thanks, for your push and being so helpful .

Answer (score 1):

In your existing code make the following changes.

this checks for leap year.

- if it is divisible by 4 and not a century year, its is a leap year
- or if is divisible by 400 it is a leap year.
- otherwise, it isn't.

```
boolean N2 =  (year %4 == 0 && year %100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
```

Now just use the negation of the boolean to test for non leap year.

```
if (N1)
    System.out.println(". This month has 31 days");
else if (N4) {
    System.out.println(". This month has 30 days");
} else if (month == 2) {
    boolean N2 = (year %4 == 0 && year %100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
    if (N2) {
        System.out.println("This month has 29 days");
    } else {// must not be leap year.
        System.out.println("This month has 28 days");
    }
} else {
    System.out.printf("Bad month(%d) entered", month);
}
```

- Also, you should only use one Scanner for all console input.

**An alternative approach**

In case you didn't know, the `enhanced switch statement` introduced in Java 13 would be perfect for this.

- it takes multiple cases
- and returns an argument for processing.

```
public class Q11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the month (1-12)");
        int month = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the year");
        int year = scanner.nextInt();

        boolean isLeapYear =  (year %4 == 0 && year %100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
        String proclamation = switch(month) {
            case 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 -> "This month has 31 days.";
            case 4,6,9,11 -> "This month has 30 days";
            case 2 -> "This month has %d days".formatted(isLeapYear ? 29 : 28);
            default -> "Bad month (%d) entered.".formatted(month);
        };   
        System.out.println(proclamation);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am able to understand this. Wouldn't `(!N2)` encompass all other months except the February of leap years?

Comment: SO seems to be having problems today.  I was in the middle of giving further detail when it went down.  See my updated answer

Comment: This is my first week of coding, so I didn't know about the switch statement.  I tried assigning multiple cases to a boolean and it didn't work, thought it would be ridiculous to write a new line of code for each of them and there had to be a better way. This solves that, thank you, I learnt something new today.

Comment: I was just showing switch for extra information.  And your method is fine with a few changes.  And one of the few ways to do it without using a switch.  Not bad for being new to programming. Welcome to StackOverflow!